# Multiple copies of books, only show those which are unavailable _ SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Okay, so I have a library style database and I want to grab the name of all books which are sold out.  The book is considered sold out if all the copies have been rented out. The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT Book.Title, Physical_book.book_available AS Available
FROM Book
JOIN Physical_book ON Book.book_id = Physical_Book.book_id
WHERE Physical_book.book_available = 'n';
```

My Physical_Media Table has the attribute book_available which tells you if the book is available with either an N or a Y.  In this table books are repeated if there is more than one copy.  Meaning, if the book is `Title One` then I have three twos for `Title One`  All with the same Book_ID being `2`.  2 out of the three of these books are marked with an `n` and the other is marked with a `y`.  Technically and what I wannt, is this query to pull only those that have ALL the books sold out.  Since it returns the result of `Title ONe` it is clearly not working correctly.  Any ideas?

Example of Table

```
/* Physical_Book Table */
INSERT INTO Physical_Book (Physical_ID, Book_ID, Book_available)
VALUES (1,1,'y');
INSERT INTO Physical_Book (Physical_ID, Book_ID, Book_available)
VALUES (2,1,'n');
INSERT INTO Physical_Book (Physical_ID, Book_ID, Book_available)
VALUES (3,1,'n');

/*Book Table*/
INSERT INTO Book (Book_ID, author_id, genre_id, title, copyright)
VALUES (1, Tammy, Horror, Book One, 1999)
```

With JW Query

```
SELECT Book.Title, Physical_book.book_available AS Available
FROM Book
JOIN Physical_book ON Book.book_id = Physical_Book.book_id
Group BY Book.title, Physical_book.book_available
HAVING COUNT (*) = COUNT (CASE WHEN book_available = 'n' THEN 1 END);
```

Comment: remove `Physical_book.book_available AS Available` and also on the `GROUP BY` clause because it does not make since you only want to get the books where ALL are sold out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  ID, title
FROM    Physical_Book
GROUP   BY ID, title
HAVING  COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN book_available = 'n' THEN 1 END)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/48f7d/1)

Assuming you have this records,

```
╔════╦═══════════╦════════════════╗
║ ID ║   TITLE   ║ BOOK_AVAILABLE ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Title One ║ y              ║
║  1 ║ Title One ║ n              ║
║  1 ║ Title One ║ n              ║
║  2 ║ Title Two ║ n              ║
║  2 ║ Title Two ║ n              ║
╚════╩═══════════╩════════════════╝
```

The expected output of the query is

```
╔════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║   TITLE   ║
╠════╬═══════════╣
║  2 ║ Title Two ║
╚════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does exactly as my query does above.  It returns all 18 Book titles with the column `Available` being set to N on all of them. We do want to grab the results that are labeled as `n` or not available but we do not want to show records which do have a copy of the book available.  Your picture is exactly what I am talking about but the query returns all 18 Book titles

Comment: maybe you have missed something else.

Comment: Hopefully that helps? THe JOIN is in the first part of my Query (first part of quesiton)  So what does the `THEN 1 END` do exactly or what is it??? I am new to DB

Comment: try this, `SELECT a.Book_ID,
  a.Author_ID,
  a.Title
FROM Book a
  INNER JOIN Physical_Book b
   ON a.Book_ID = b.Book_ID
GROUP BY  a.Book_ID,
   a.Author_ID,
   a.Title
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN b.book_available = 'n' THEN 1 END)`

Comment: probably you are new with this: `COUNT(CASE WHEN b.book_available = 'n' THEN 1 END)` what it basically does is it counts the record only when the value of `book_available  = 'n'`

Comment: because it will also group the book with `y` and `n`.

Comment: ohhh right, never thought of it that way...another +10 for you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
select title
from book
where not exists
(select title
from book
where available = 'Y'
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried something similar but this simply outputs all the books without the `y` so in otherwords, Title One shows up twice.  In reality it shouldn't show up at all beacuse it has one record with a `y`